# Behavior of \b [Word Boundary] in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

By accident, I discovered that in python regex `\b` doesn't necessarily mean the end of a **token**; it sometimes literally means the end of a **word**

Consider the following sentence:

```
sentence = 'This was the view of a conservative who voted with the government in all his eight years as a member of the House of Commons,'
```

So if we want to find the term: "House of Commons" as a term not part of anything else; we could use the following regex pattern:

```
sentence = 'This was the view of a conservative who voted with the government in all his eight years as a member of the House of Commons,'
import regex as re
regex_pat = r'\bHouse of Commons\b'

result = re.findall(regex_pat, sentence)
print(result)
```

Luckily for my current case, I get exactly what I want:

```
['House of Commons']
```

Notice 'House of Commons' NOT **'House of Commons,'** with the comma (,) attached at the end of the word commons,

So my question is how does `\b` behave in python regex? If I substitute the comma (,) attached to the word commons with any number; I get ZERO results!!

```
new_sentence = 'This was the view of a conservative who voted with the government in all his eight years as a member of the House of Commons9'
regex_pat = r'\bHouse of Commons\b'

result = re.findall(regex_pat, new_sentence)
print(result)
```

I get an empty list!
`[]`

**What if I wanted anything like:**

```
['House of Commons']
['House of Commons,']
['House of Commons!']
['House of Commons*']
['House of Commons9']
```

Comment: I don't think `\b` behaves any differently in Python compared to anywhere else. Word boundaries are where a word *likely* ends - say, the next character is a comma, dot, space. Non-word characters. Also `\bHouse of Commons\b` would only ever match "House of Commons" because there is nothing in the pattern to allow for any extra characters. The same way `/ab/` will not match "abc" - pattern doesn't allow for it.

Comment: @VLAZ So the question does regex make a distinction between a non-word character like (punctuations) and (numbers) at the end of a word??... I always thought ```\b``` means the end of a token.. but it seems to work only when that token ends with a letter or punctuation it seems, am I correct?

Comment: It's a *word* boundary. So, it's not just a token: `\by\b` is not going to match "xyz" because the "y" is surrounded by word characters. `y\b` will match "xy" but not "yz". While ``\by` will match "yz" but not "xy".

Comment: `\b` is an anchor which matches a `word boundary`, a gap between a `word character` and
a `non-word character`. Word characters consist of alphabets, digits and an underscore
character. As the string `the House of Commons9` does not include the gap between `s` and `9`, the pattern `r'\bHouse of Commons\b'` does not match. If you want to detect
the gap between an alphabet character and a non-alphabet character (including the end
of the string), you can say `r'\bHouse of Commons(?![[:aplha:]])'`